# java scanner nullpointer exception when end of file is reached

Tags: java, file-io

Okay I may be doing something stupid or this should be a simple fix but basically I have a text file I am reading from with a scanner object and I am getting a nullpointer exception when I reach the end of the file I was wondering how to get fix this

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileAccess {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner s = null;

    try {
      s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("move_list.txt")));
      while (s.hasNext()) {
          System.out.println(s.next());
      }
    }
    finally {
      if (s != null) {
        s.close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once it reaches the end I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.util.regex.Matcher.toMatchResult(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.util.Scanner.myCoreNext(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(libgcj.so.10)
   at FileAccess.main(FileAccess.java:13)
```

Comment: Why are you using the scanner? Why not just loop over `bufferedReader.readLine()`

Comment: seems to work fine for me for some random file I tried.

Comment: Can you provide a sample file that you can't correctly parse?

Comment: Well I plan on doing more with the code, this is just a stripped down version of what I am doing to highlight the issue An example file I am tried with is fruits.txt with a fruit on each line  pear
orange
blueberry
peach
grape
banana
plum

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = s.nextLine();
  System.out.println(line);
}
s.close();
```

Comment: The file I would like to use this code with contains about 400 lines with 18 numbers on each line, I want to pull the last number from each line so I don't think I can use the nextLine() method